echo command throwing "Filename too long"
I have a really large data stored in a single Unix variable. it is a very very big JSON (approx 100k lines).
rules = '<BIG JSON>';
echo $rules > filename.txt

The second line throws an error  "File name too long".
I also tried doing echo $rules and same problem. Any thoughts?
Expectation is the contents of the variable (no matter how big) should get transferred to a file.

First, always quote your expansions. ShellCheck will catch things like that. Second, there's an upper limit to how long a command line can be. Shell is probably not the best choice there; or keep your data in a file of its own from the beginning.

What system are you on? Does it support bash process substitution? e.g., cat <(echo "${rules}") > filename.txt

Please [edit] your question and add more details. Are you using WSL? Please confirm that this problem occurs only with the big JSON value, not with smaller values and the same filename in the same current directory. The spaces before and after = are wrong. Make sure you copy&paste the code you ran, don't re-type.  Use https://www.shellcheck.net/

You don't need process substitution. echo "$rules" > filename.txt should work, if not fine, than at least not without causing any issue with the output redirection. A better question is how you got 100k lines of text in a shell variable in the first place.
